# P for trend for quartiles in linear regression in SAS

Tags: p-value, sas, trend

I am using PROC GLM in SAS to run a linear regression model and have a continuous exposure variable that for a secondary analysis I have categorized into quartiles. I know I can use a contrast statement to get a p for linear trend of the quartiles, but am unsure how to write the statement because they are not equally spaced. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I used `proc iml`:

```
proc iml;  
    value={100 117 128 143};  
    contr_val=orpol(value,4);  
    print contr_val;  
quit;
```